# Webflow with self hosted ghost blog

Tags: ghost-blog, webflow

Is there a way to run webflow & ghost together where - https://example.com/* is served by webflow and https://example.com/blog/* is served via my self hosted ghost server.

How do I put the IP of my ghost server in my domain's DNS record?

Or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use subdomains instead of an extended URL.
Reference `blog.example.com` to the IP address of your ghost server.

To reference:

1. Connect a custom domain to the webflow site.
2. Go to the DNS manager of the custom domain.

If you have an IP address for the ghost server, then:

3. Add an `A record` with `NAME = [subdomain]` (here [subdomain] = blog) and `Value = [IP address]`

else If you have a domain name for the ghost server, then:

3. Add an `CNAME record` with `NAME = [subdomain]` (here [subdomain] = blog) and `Value = [Domain Name]`

> You can only achieve this if you have an active webflow hosting using
> a paid site plan which enables you to add a custom domain.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using a subdomain for your blog, for SEO reasons.

So if you want to use your hosted Webflow site in combination with a (own hosted) Ghost blog on the same domain name, for example on `yourdomain.com/blog/` one way of achieving this by setting up a reverse proxy.

Your can read the whole set up here:
https://signoz.io/blog/webflow-ghost-subdirectory/

Answer (score 0):

You would need to setup an independent reverse proxy server - using a web server such as [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) or [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/).  You would then point your root domain to this server and reverse proxy to both your Webflow site and your Ghost site depending on the URL route.

Alternatively you could try to do this using Cloudflare Workers (Google for "using cloudflare worker as reverse proxy") or for a no code / managed solution you could try a service such as [HostForward](https://hostforward.io) which does it all for you.